# How to apply user defined style(CSS) to React-Treebeard?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm working with **treebeard** in my react project.
when I try to add a user-defined style it's not getting applied to the container.
I have tried different methods to achieve this. 
I tried to define the style from  tag, tried to define style.css in a different file, import it and assign it to style in *Treedeard* tag.

the main goal is to change the background color and the position.

Here is my code:

workspace.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import {Treebeard} from 'react-treebeard';
import data from "./data";

export class WorkSpace extends React. Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {data}
        };
        this.onToggle = this.onToggle.bind(this);
        const decorators = {
            Container: (props) => {
                return (
                    <div style={props.backgroundColor="yellow"}>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        };
    }
    onToggle(node, toggled){
        const {cursor, data} = this.state.data;
        if (cursor) {
            this.setState(() => ({cursor, active: false}));
        }
        node.active = true;
        if (node.children) { 
            node.toggled = toggled; 
        }
        this.setState(() => ({cursor: node, data: Object.assign({}, data)}));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="base_container">
                    <h3>Select Component</h3>
                    <div className="components">
                        <Treebeard 
                            data={data} 
                            onToggle={this.onToggle}
                            style = {style_components}
                            decorators={this.decorators}
                        />
                    </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: have you looked over https://github.com/storybookjs/react-treebeard#style doc?

Comment: yeah...!  I tried to implement it